# Redshift Regular Expression

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I need help with two instances where I need to utilize Reguar Expressions.
In this example `A18040500198 ARM88` I need to extract `ARM88` and using the same example I need to extract `A18040500198`

Would anybody be able to help me with this. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: if the string format is consistent, you can use [split_part](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html) function

Comment: please be exact and specific on what you are trying to do - include examples of input and output data and also include examples of what you have already tried, together with error messages or issues.. update your question with all of this info.

Answer (score -1):

"(A[0-9]*)|(ARM88))" would return both strings, but many others too.

If you need to only return **exactly** those two strings, use "(A18040500198)|(ARM88)"

More information on what you specifically want the RegEx to do would be useful.